# Google Optimize giving Error: The editor page URL is matched by targeting rules of a previous page which will be applied instead

Tags: optimization, google-optimize

Any guidance on how can I resolve this issue? If I try to change the rules I am getting another error as: The editor page URL is matched by targeting rules of a previous page which will be applied instead.

[image: Error]

I really appreciate it if anyone can help me resolve this error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I head similar issue when:

1. Page 1 uses regex match targeting
2. Page 2 uses regex match targeting

Patterns were completely different - there could be no intersection, yet I still got the error.
I changed Page 2 targeting to "contains" - and the error disappeared.

Go figure.